# onclick event doesn't wait for file selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use file input in html using a single button.

My html:

```
<input type="file" class="btn btn-purple" id="inventory_csv" name="inventory_csv" onchange="this.form.submit()" style="display:none">
<button name="upload_inventory" id="upload_inventory" class="btn btn-purple btn-labeled fa" onclick="chooseFile()">Upload Inventory</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function chooseFile() {
    $("#inventory_csv").click();
}
```

The script doesn't work properly. When I click the `upload_inventory` button, it does not wait for me to select the file. It opens the file selection dialog box and navigates to the next page.

I want it to wait for me to select the file and then go to the next page.

Comment: Default behavior of button is `submit`

Comment: Set its type as `<button type="button" onclick="chooseFile()">Upload Inventory</button>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default behavior of `button` is `submit`, set its type to `button`

```
<button type="button" onclick="chooseFile()">Upload Inventory</button>
```

OR, Prevent its default behaviour like

```
<button onclick="return chooseFile()">Upload Inventory</button>
```

*Script*

```
function chooseFile() {
     $("#inventory_csv").click();
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can detect if a file was selected and submit the form afterwards.

```
  $(function() {
     $("input:file").change(function (){
       var fileName = $(this).val();
       //submit form or whatever
     });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

As Satpal mentionned it, what happens is that the button default behavior is also triggered and submits the form.

You can either prevent default behavior or change the button type:

```
<button type="button" ...></button>
```

Or

```
function chooseFile() {
    $("#inventory_csv").click();
    return false;
}
```